# Function subtract vs function absdiff

Tags: c++, opencv

When running the following code to get visual on the differences of the pictures

```
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat image1 = imread("1.bmp");
    Mat image2 = imread("2.bmp");
    Mat differenceImg1;
    Mat differenceImg2;
    subtract(image1, image2, differenceImg1);
    imshow("subtract", differenceImg1);
    absdiff(image1, image2, differenceImg2);
    imshow("absdiff", differenceImg2);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

I get the same result
[image]

Is there a difference between these two? Which and when is better to use?

Comment: It's the same difference between "y=a-b" and "y=abs(a-b)". If "a-b" is positive, the result will be the same, obviously. Absdiff is commutative, btw. In the first case negative values may be clamped to 0, depending on data type.

Comment: There may be a difference, but I'm not sure if it's an absolute difference.

Answer (score 3):

If you `subtract` one image from the other it will give an image that only contains the areas where the second image has higher values than the first image.

Whereas `absdiff` will give the absolute difference between two images.